# How to get Host's "processes info" and "disk space usage info" when in a docker container

Tags: docker

I'm making a system-performance-monitor-tool, which needs cpu-usage, memory-usage, disk-usage and currnet-processes-info.

I already/kinda finished it out of docker, but the installation and uninstallation is too complicated, so I'm trying to finish it in docker.

I have already mount `/proc/stat` and `/proc/meminfo` in container so I can directly read the host's cpu-usage and memory-usage now.

Now I have trouble getting disk-usage and currnet processes. Normal in host I will run `df` and `ps auxf` to get them, but it can't be done in a container. I read the document of procps but still confused.

(Also I knew how but I really don't want to use remote-command with ssh because **I just don't want to do key-based authentication**. Please don't recommend this way).

Is there a way like *mount something into container* that can make it possible to read host's "processes info" and "disk space usage info" in a docker container?

Comment: Having a docker container access the host resource monitoring and run commands sounds like a huge security risk.

Comment: @mhovd it's no more of a security risk than running your performance monitoring tool *outside* of a container.

Comment: If your application needs the network/process/metrics data from the host system, it seems like you don't really want any of Docker's isolation features.  Why run this tool in a container at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze For easy installation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way like mount something into container that can make it possible to read host's "processes info" and "disk space usage info" in a docker container?

Sure. You can mount the host's root filesystem and the `/proc` filesystem into the container like this:

```
docker run -v /proc:/host/proc -v /:/host/root ...
```

Then inside the container you can discover host process information by inspecting the `/host/proc` directory, and you can see filesystem utilization by running `df /host/root`.

This exact technique is used when running [node-exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) inside a container; [this document](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/quickstart/docker-compose-linux/) shows a relatively common configuration.

Note that you won't be able to use `ps` in this case, but you can read entries from `/host/proc` directly.

---

Alternately, you can run your container in the host pid namespace:

```
docker run --pid=host -v /:/host/root ...
```

This allows you to run `ps` in the container to see host processes.